# php currency setting based on user location

Tags: php

I need to change currency based on user location. This is my code

```
<?php
  $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  
  $location = unserialize( file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) );
 

  if($location["geoplugin_countryCode"] === "US")
  {
     // block to set us currency
  }
  else{ 
     // user can choose their own currency from array (excluding us)
  }
?>
```

I uploaded it on a server, and to check if the functionality works correctly or not and I used different vpn chrome extension. The problem is all the time else part is alone gets executed even when I choose us as vpn server. I don't know What is causing this problem.

Comment: What does `var_dump($location["geoplugin_countryCode"]);` show?

Comment: IP geolocation is unreliable to begin with, and a user may wish to view pricing in a currency that differs from their location. Ensure that the user can set their preference, and that geolocation is a _suggestion_ at best.

Comment: Use javascript to déterminate this.

Comment: It’s unclear if the problem is that your ip is not changing, or the response for that http request isn’t what you expect, please check and edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the issue is that you use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.
If you are using a proxy, you should use `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`

Comment: A vpn is not a proxy. “Most probably” - there’s some truth here but it’s not the best idea to write an answer based on an assumption.